# Getting "There is no trusted URLs configured for the app deployment" when making a REST call into an app from an html page in a different server

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

Here's the setup:

1. SharePoint on premises: http://sharepoint-site.com
2. A 3rd party web site (just an html page, no sharepoint: `http://web-site.com/test.html`) needs to make a call into sharepoint to retrieve a list of all available lists in the root web
3. I created a sharepoint-hosted app (with list permissions) and installed it into `http://sharepoint-site.com`; its URL is `http://app-c06fc375b9447b.apps.sharepoint-site.com/MyApp`

`http://web-site.com/test.html` has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>

<script>

        var hostweburl = "http://sharepoint-site.com/";
        var relsiteurl = ""; // leave empty if root web
        var appweburl = "http://app-c06fc375b9447b.apps.sharepoint-site.com/MyApp";


        $(document).ready(function () {
            // resources are in URLs in the form:
            // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
            var scriptbase = hostweburl + relsiteurl + "/_layouts/15/";

            // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "MicrosoftAjax.js", function() {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.debug.js",
                    function () {
                        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.debug.js",
                            function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.debug.js", continueLoading); });
                    });
            });
        });


        function continueLoading() {
            getDocumentList();
        }

        function getDocumentList()
        {

            var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

            executor.executeAsync({
                url:appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists?target='" + hostweburl + "'",
                method: "GET",
                headers: {  "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: successHandler, 
                error:  errorHandler
            });

            function successHandler(data) {
                console.log(data);   
            }

            function errorHandler(a, b, c) {
                console.log(c);
            }           
        };  
</script>
</head>
```

When I load `http://app-c06fc375b9447b.apps.sharepoint-site.com/MyApp` I get the following error in JS console:

> There is no trusted URLs configured for the app deployment.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. In appmanifest.xml there is AppPrincipal/Internal entry; it has an optional AllowedRemoteHostUrl attribute which shoudl be set to `http://web-site.com` from my example

```
<AppPrincipal>
  <Internal  AllowedRemoteHostUrl="http://web-site.com"/>
</AppPrincipal>
```

Comment: I am having same issue but in my case its on provider hosted app. Any idea?